# JQuery How to set the value of a hidden field to the selected value of a dropdownlist

Tags: jquery

I am using MVC 3 and I am trying to take the selected value of a dropdownlist and store it into a hidden field.  YearList is my dropdown and DOBYear is the hidden field.  The error I am getting is

htmlfile: Unexpected call to method or property access.

Anyone have any ideas what might be happening?  Seems like it should be a pretty easy and common thing to do.

```
$(function () {
    $("#YearList").change(function () {
        $('#DOBYear').html($('#YearList').val()); 
    });
});
```

Thanks,

Rhonda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for:

```
$(function () {
    $("#YearList").change(function () {
        $('#DOBYear').val(this.value);
    });
});
```

(Use `.val()` to populate the value of the hidden input instead of `.html()`)